# Javascript Switch statement not providing the correct result

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to detect the browser and browser version for a web application

The code for determining the browser is -

```
function get_browser() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem, M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
        tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || '');
    }
    if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
        tem = ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
        if (tem != null) { return 'Opera ' + tem[1]; }
    }
    M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) { M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]); }
    return M[0];
}
```

The code for determining the version is -

```
function get_browser_version() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem, M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
        tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || '');
    }
    if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
        tem = ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
        if (tem != null) { return 'Opera ' + tem[1]; }
    }
    M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) { M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]); }
    return M[1];
}
```

The rest of the code is -

```
var browser = get_browser().toLowerCase();
var browser_version = get_browser_version();

alert(browser, browser_version);

switch (browser) {
    case 'safari':
        if (browser_version < 5) {
            $('#BrowserVersionModal').modal('show');
        }
        break;
    case 'firefox':
        if (browser_version < 28) {
            $('#BrowserVersionModal').modal('show');
        }
        break;
    case 'ie':
        if (browser_version < 9) {
            $('#BrowserVersionModal').modal('show');
        }
        break;
    case 'opera':
        if (browser_version < 6) {
            $('#BrowserVersionModal').modal('show');
        }
        break;
    default:

}
```

The alert indicates that the browser is ie and the version is 11 but I never see the modal being displayed.  If I add an alert in the case statement for ie, it never is shown either.  What am I missing?

Comment: may be because 11 not lesser than 9?

Comment: If I put the alert before checking the version number it still does not show.  I also tried to change the less than to 12 and still no modal.

Comment: If I remove the version check .. I still do not get the modal.

Comment: Who writes this in your question: "The alert indicates that the browser is ie and the version is 11"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues here.

`return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || '');` in the browser check doesn't give you something that will match 'ie' in the case sensitive switch statement.

The other issue is that `browser_version < 9` will not evaluate to true if the version is 11.

Comment: This actually led me to the problem.  Get_Browser function and Get_Browser_Version were both returning the browser and version for IE.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
case 'ie':
    if (browser_version < 9) {
        $('#BrowserVersionModal').modal('show');
    }
    break;
```

you say - if it is IE and less than 9 - so ie 11 is not triggered, because it is > 9

Answer (score 0):

I think because the version is 11, the condition `if (browser_version < 9)` will be false so the modal will not show.

Answer (score 0):

Try followed;

```
var versions = {
  ie: 9,
  opera: 6,
  firefox: 28,
  safari: 5
};

if(!versions[browser]) {
  alert('Unknown browser: '+browser);
} else if (browser_version < versions[browser]) {
  alert('poor browser');
} else {
  alert('good browser');
}
```